# Disaply custom page / tab in Jenkins project

Tags: testing, build, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have a project in Jenkins , every time the build finished in generated a custom html file that i want Jenkins to display in the build summary / in a custom tab that will be in each build

I can save this HTML as an artifact and there will be a link to it but i want it displayed so people wont need to go to another page / download this report

any ideas ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does the [HTML Publisher Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/HTML+Publisher+Plugin) fit your bill?